# ViewLifeCycleOwner returning null when going from Main, to background to MainThread again

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-lifecycle, weak-references

I need to begin observation some milliseconds after an adapter has resolved it's views in order for them to properly receive a signal.

This method is being executed AFTER onViewCreated();

```
                pageControllerAdapter.submitList(stringVisitors, () -> {
                    if (!currentPage.hasActiveObservers()) {
                        Post.delayed(
                                () -> {
                                    Post.onMain(
                                            () -> {
                                                currentPage.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
                                                        page -> {
                                                            selector.setSelected(page);
                                                            binding.searchPages.setCurrentItem(page, true);
                                                        }
                                                );
                                            }
                                    );

                                },
                                150L,
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        );
                    }
                });
```

Where `Post.delayed()` is an `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule()` method, while `Post.onMain()` is a `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());` for Runnable posting

And something curious is happening...:

The first time the code is executed everything is ok, BUT after a configuration change an `IllegalStateException` occurs:

```
@MainThread
    @NonNull
    public LifecycleOwner getViewLifecycleOwner() {
        if (mViewLifecycleOwner == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner when "
                    + "getView() is null i.e., before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView()");
        }
        return mViewLifecycleOwner;
    }
```

BUT... if I call `getViewLifeCycleOwner()`; before entering the `.getMainLooper()` thread, in-between the `Post.delayed()` and `Post.onMain()` like this:

```
                        Post.delayed(
                                () -> {
                                    getViewLifecycleOwner();
                                    Post.onMain(
                                            () -> {
                                                currentPage.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
                                                        page -> {
                                                            selector.setSelected(page);
                                                            binding.searchPages.setCurrentItem(page, true);
                                                        }
                                                );
                                            }
                                    );

                                },
                                150L,
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        );
```

The code works....

What I suspect is happening, is this...:

```
/**
     * The provider that owns this Lifecycle.
     * Only WeakReference on LifecycleOwner is kept, so if somebody leaks Lifecycle, they won't leak
     * the whole Fragment / Activity. However, to leak Lifecycle object isn't great idea neither,
     * because it keeps strong references on all other listeners, so you'll leak all of them as
     * well.
     */
    private final WeakReference<LifecycleOwner> mLifecycleOwner;
```

The WeakReference is being GC'd inside the `Post.delayed()` (the scheduled executor) So when the method is required to be executed in the `mainThread` again, the reference has already been collected, BUT when a second execution of the method is performed in the background scheduled executor, even if the reference is not used at all, a copy of all the references involved in the method `getViewLifeCycleOwner()` are retained by the thread and escape garbage collection when going back to `mainThread`.

Is my hunch correct?

Answer (score 0):

So this was not what was happening..., yes, but partially.
The new thread was not "collecting" the WeakReference, but it was "prolonging" its lifeSpan.
How? the getViewLifeCycle() method when executed before the 150 millis dictated by the delayed method, helped bypass the IllegalStateException() and bring a copy of the LifecycleRegistry which was already destroyed by the time the method executed... Thank god, the LiveData compoent is ment to do a `return;` when the lifeCycle is already destroyed and everything ends.

The real problem had to do with null states, initial states, and the previously saved state...

The Fragment that was already present in the stack before the configuration change occurred, was being replaced with the same Fragment again, and everything because an upper layer component was ignoring equality, and this destruction was faster than the 150 millis dictated by the delayed method.

This is what was destroying the view before the `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule()` could access it.

At first I thought the problem was on the equality checks on generic enums (as it ignores new objects, but this was the opposite problem so..), but the thing that was allowing for a repeated action to pass... was in reality that an "initiating state" on said component was triggering on configuration change (to be more precise: onViewCreated), and so the equality check could not infer that the TRUE last action/Fragment was already present on the stack ...

The solution was to check for Fragment class() equality between old and new, to prevent a repeated transaction.

Another option would be to make a special case for configuration change, and make the component aware of this state, but repeated transaction/actions in general are a bad sign in any code IMO, so the best course of action would be to prevent repeating actions at all.